# Excel 2003 - Workbook_Activate bug for ActiveSheet.Calculate

Tags: vba, excel

*Context:*
Excel 2003, Windows 7 Professional SP1

1. Working on workbook A, which contains custom functions.
2. Workbook B is opened or edited
3. Back to workbook A, which `Workbook_Activate` sub is the following:

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Activate
       ActiveSheet.Calculate
   End Sub
   ```
4. This procedure should force the calculation of custom functions of workbook A, which cells display `#VALUE` during the edition of workbook B.

*Below are the bugs I get on my computer, I hope you can help me with them!*

- When the workbook (not the whole Excel window) IS NOT in state `ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal` (i.e. it is full screen or minimized)

**OR:**

- When the workbook IS in state `ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal` and the workbook has a width > 725 pixels (!)

**THEN:**

- The function `Workbook_Activate` is fired all the way (good thing).
- The function `ActiveSheet.Calculate` is not fired (or without effect).
- Breakpoints don't stop the code.
- You can't run any code that edits cells, or run `Application.CalculateFull`, without getting a display bug such as entire ranges where the text or border vanish until the ranges have been selected.

**PROBLEM SOLVING:**

In procedure `Workbook_Activate`, if we add `ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal` before `ActiveSheet.Calculate`:

When the workbook IS NOT in state `ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal` and the Excel window IS maximized

- ONLY in this case, the bugs remain. It's the only case where function ActiveSheet.Calculate is not fired. `ActiveWindow`methods don't fire either.

*Obs.:* `Application.EnableEvents = False` doesn't change anything. (It's probably not even triggered.)

Thank you!

Comment: `ActiveSheet` possibly isn't what you think it is.  Maybe try to `Activate` the worksheet you want before you run the `Calculate` method, or at least debug it with something like `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name` so you are sure exactly which sheet is currently active.  It's because of this potential confusion many people recommend never using `ActiveSheet` but always specifying the sheet directly.

Comment: ActiveSheet is correct, I already checked. Actually, everything goes normally (debug.print, msgbox...), except the .Calculate or .CalculateFull methods don't fire correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to avoid the bug.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

[Edit]
... But it was not acceptable, because the calculation was set to "Manual" by default on any other opened workbook.

The best solution is here: [Excel 2003 - Display bug with conditional formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633326/excel-2003-display-bug-with-conditional-formatting/44634116#44634116)